# Make c++ interpret a pointer to NULL as zero

Tags: c++, pointers, null

I have this kind of code

```
two->height   = max(two->right->height, two->left->height);
```

One of the two->right or  two->left can be a pointer to null so the program will seg fault . I am looking for , if the two->left is null it will get transformed into zero so the two->right will be automatically true .

Is there any trick that can overcome this issue ?

Comment: A bit unclear what the question is but `nullptr` doesn’t have an integral type and can't be converted to integer.

Comment: @RawN I'm pretty sure the OP doesn't want to treat `two->left` as zero, the OP wants to treat `two->left->height` as zero if `two->left` is a null pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can also work:

```
two->height   =       max(
                         ( two->right != nullptr ? two->right->height : 0 ),
                         ( two->left  != nullptr ? two->left->height  : 0 )
                         );
```

Comment: Adding that `== nullptr` reversed the meaning and totally broke it

Comment: NULL is null in c and nullptr is the null in c++ ?

Comment: @ItsYou No. There are `0`, `NULL` and `nullptr`. `nullptr` is of type `std::nullptr_t`. In C++ you should prefer `nullptr` over `NULL` and `0`.

Comment: @ItsYou: Basically, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You are first going to want to perform a check on the left and right pointers and see if they are null. Something along the lines of:

```
if(two->right == NULL) {
    ...
}
else if(two->left == NULL) {
    ...
}
else {
    two->height = max(two->right->height, two->left->height);
}
```

There are many ways to deal with pointers being NULL. I just picked a simple one for an example.

Comment: This is a very verbose way to do it, and will result in much code duplication. The OP is specifically looking for something expressive.